# What is the difference between "myvar=me" and "myvar"="me"?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've been wondering what is the difference between `"myvar=me"` and  `"myvar"="me"` in a batch file?

It might make a difference to my program which is a rock, paper, and scissors game.

Comment: Two quotes? If you are talking about the `set` command, why not you just test it and see what happens?

Comment: In the absence of context, we can but speculate.

Answer (score 1):

The difference can be easily seen on running a batch file with following lines:

```
@set "myvar=me"
@set "myvar"="me"
set myvar
@pause
```

The first line defines an environment variable with name `myvar` with value `me`.

The second line defines an environment variable with strange name `myvar"` with value `"me`.

The third line is output by Windows command interpreter after preprocessing the command line before execution and outputs all environment variables of which name start with `myvar` with environment variable name, equal sign and environment variable value.

And fourth line halts batch execution until a key is pressed to see output of third line in case of batch file was executed with a double click.

So the first three lines of output are:

```
set myvar
myvar=me
myvar"="me
```

For details on how to define an environment variable right with correct assigning a value read answer on:

[Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

It explains with text and examples why the syntax `set "variable=value"` is usually the best.

Comment: Thank you for the helping me guys.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on context.

In case of usage inside the `set` command it can treat quotes as a part of a variable name and a value:

```
>set "a"="111"
```

'

```
>set
a"="111
...
```

But not in this case:

```
>set "a=111"
```

'

```
>set
a=111
...
```

Internal logic of the `cmd.exe` is simple is that as it eats character by character and removes quotes from the most left and right parts of a string.

Here is another context (file `test.bat`):

```
@echo off

call :TEST "1111"="2222"
call :TEST "1111","2222"
call :TEST "1111";"2222"
call :TEST "1111"-"2222"

exit /b 0
:TEST 
echo -%1- -%2-
```

'

```
-"1111"- -"2222"-
-"1111"- -"2222"-
-"1111"- -"2222"-
-"1111"-"2222"- --
```

As you see some characters treated here as a parameter separator in a command line.

Personally I prefer to write the `set "var=value"` without ^-escape characters before the `&` and `)` characters which can be part of a file path.

Comment: This answer is inexact. In all Windows versions the delimiters for command-line parameters are comma, semicolon and equal sign (besides space and TAB) as explicitly documented in many sites, like [this one](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting).